# is it possible to create a website inside an website?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I want to load YouTube in a certain frame inside my website. I am just able to embed a particular video only. Is this possible to include YouTube inside my website in a particular frame?

Comment: What does this have to do with java/python?

Comment: Use relevant tags when asking questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe to achieve this but the **origin website can choose to deny this.**

Youtube does deny this. You would see an error like
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: oh ok !  But is there any way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use An iframe is used to display a web page within a web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp" height="600" width="600"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

W3Schools Reference - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

But in the case of YouTube you get an error

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “SAMEORIGIN” from “https://www.youtube.com/”, site does not permit cross-origin framing from “https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_height_width”
```

This is because YouTube has denied cross-orgin framing.
You can use https://www.youtube.com/embed/ for embedding videos.
Refer for Documentation from YouTube - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: No, not of my knowledge - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy